# Find coefficients of polynomial that has zeros at certain points

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, fourier-analysis, recursive-algorithms

Given a list of values z<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>, ..., z<sub>n-1</sub> (possibly with repetitions), show how to find the coefficients of a polynomial P(x) of degree-bound n + 1 that has zeros only at z<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>, ..., z<sub>n-1</sub> (possibly with repetitions). Try to find a solution or algorithm that can run in time O(nlg<sup>2</sup>n).

What I've come up with:
I know that P(x) has a zero at zj iff P(x) is a multiple of (x - z<sub>j</sub>).
Therefore, we can check if `P(x) mod (x - z`<sub>j</sub>`) = 0`
But I'm not sure how to get that runtime or how to proceed further.

Comment: this may help you http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ams011a/Winter08/PDF/11Asn7.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $p(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(X-z_k)$? Use divide-and-conquer and FFT based polynomial multiplication (Schönhage-Strassen) for a fast construction of the product.